# Updating db for items in shopping cart is adding both items into one line

Tags: php

When i process my shopping cart with two items. The database updates each items size with the new available quantity, but it seems if there are more than one item in the cart, then the second/third/forth items size updates fine with the new available quantity but the first item picks the others items quantity and adds them to sizes detail AND updates items own sizes details.

My adjust inventory details within my order confirmation page

//adjust inventory

```
  $itemQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
  $iresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemQ);
  $items = json_decode($iresults['items'],true);

foreach($items as $item){
 $newsizes = array();
 $item_id = $item['id'];
 $productQ = $db->query("SELECT sizes FROM products WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
 $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
 $sizes = sizesToArray($product['sizes']);

 foreach($sizes as $size){
   if($size['size'] == $item['size']){
   $q = $size['quantity'] - $item['quantity'];
   $newSizes[] = array('size' => $size['size'],'quantity' => $q);
  }else{
  $newSizes[] = array('size' => $size['size'],'quantity' => $size['quantity']);
 }
}
 $sizesString = sizesToString($newSizes);
 $db->query("UPDATE products SET sizes = '{$sizesString}' WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
}
```

my functions sizeToString and sizesToArray which are stored in a helpers file

```
function sizesToArray($string){
$sizesArray = explode(',',$string);
$returnArray = array();
foreach($sizesArray as $size){
  $s = explode(':',$size);
  $returnArray[] = array('size' => $s[0], 'quantity' => $s[1]);
}
return $returnArray;
}

function sizesToString($sizes){
$sizesString = '';
foreach($sizes as $size){
  $sizesString .= $size['size'].':'.$size['quantity'].',';
}
$trimmed = rtrim($sizesString, ',');
return $trimmed;
}
```

I have gone through my code and i cannot see a reason why it's doing what it is doing. 
My thoughts are if my code was looping then each items when its updated in the database would have the same problem, not just the first item.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT Helpers.php

```
function sizesToArray($string){
$sizesArray = explode(',',$string);
$returnArray = array();
foreach($sizesArray as $size){
  $s = explode(':',$size);
  $returnArray[] = array('size' => $s[0], 'quantity' => $s[1]);
}
return $returnArray;
}

function sizesToString($sizes){
$sizesString = '';
foreach($sizes as $size){
  $sizesString .= $size['size'].':'.$size['quantity'].',';
}
$trimmed = rtrim($sizesString, ',');
return $trimmed;
}
```

1) - contents of the cart
In the db table cart the string of items is saved like this

```
  [{"id":"247","size":"W5000W","quantity":2}]
  [{"id":"242","size":"MK120","quantity":"2"}]
```

2) - contens of products
before cart checkout the sizes string looked like this

```
 Prod id: 247
 sizes: W5000W:20 
 Prod id: 242
 sizes: MK120:20
```

3) expected result after checkout:

```
  Prod id: 247
  sizes: W5000W:18 
  Prod id: 242
  sizes: MK120:18
```

4) actual result after checkout:
After cart checkout the sizes string looked like this (after i ordered two of each item)

```
Prod id: 247
sizes: W5000W:18, MK120:18
Prod id: 242
sizes: MK120:18
```

NOTE: prod id 247 was added to the cart first,

EDIT 18/9

I have an select box that shows my available quantity

```
  <select name="size" id="size" class="form-control">
         <option value=""></option>
         <?php foreach($size_array as $string) {
         $string_array = explode(':', $string);
         $size = $string_array['0'];
         $available = $string_array['1'];
        if ($available > 0){
            echo '<option value="'.$size.'" data-available="'.$available.'">'.$size.' 
            ('.$available.' Available)</option>';
        }
        if ($available <= 0){
          echo '<option value="">No more left</option>';
        }
      } ?>
     </select><br>
```

and this at the bottom of my products page:

```
 jQuery('#size').change(function(){
  var available = jQuery('#size option:selected').data("available");
  jQuery('#available').val(available);
 });
```

I have this in my footer, which is the validation for the stock quantity. In theory what i am writing works but doesn't want to work in reality.

```
function add_to_cart(){
  jQuery('#product_errors').html("");
  var size = jQuery('#size').val();
  var quantity = jQuery('#quantity').val();
  var available = parseInt(jQuery('#available').val());
  var error = '';
  var data = jQuery('#add_product_form').serialize();

  if (size == '' || quantity == '' || quantity == 0){
    error += '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" i 
    id="product_errors"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
    label="close">&times;</a><strong>Error!</strong> You must select a size 
      and quantity before continuing.</div>';
   jQuery('#product_errors').html(error);
   return;
   } else if (quantity > available){
     error += '<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" 
   id="product_errors"><a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria- 
   label="close">&times;</a><strong>Error!</strong> We have only 
   '+available+' available. </div>';
    jQuery('#product_errors').html(error);
    return;
  } else{
   $.ajax({
  url : 'add_cart.php',
  method : 'post',
  data : data,
  success : function(){
    location.reload();
    window.location.href = "basket.php";
  },
  error : function(){alert("Something went wrong");},
  });
  }
  }
```

Comment: You would want to do this in one SQL statement - something like `UPDATE products, cart SET products.sizes = products.sizes - cart.sizes WHERE cart.cart_id = 17 AND cart.product_id = products.id`

Comment: i don't want to update sizes in my cart as its a string of items named items. I just want to update my products table, sizes field with the new size value, and not add the 2nd item to the first item added to the cart..

Comment: If your inventory table has the columns PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_SIZE, PRODUCT_QUANTITY you can simply iterate over the items in the shopping cart and for each one of them update the inventory of the corresponding product & size with the new quantity.

Comment: inside my products table i have a field called: sizes which stored information like: ABCDE:20 - this is product model:quantity available.

I think the issue here is this code when adjusting the inventory

           $sizesString = sizesToString($newSizes);
          $db->query("UPDATE products SET sizes = '{$sizesString}' WHERE id = 
         '{$item_id}'");

I dont think its going from product 1; updating the quantity available, then only products 2.. and so on..

Comment: to add to this, you mention cart table in your first reply, my cart stores products like this: [{"id":"1","size":"VSK3000B","quantity":"1"}]

Comment: Your data model is flawed - consider using an inventory table with 3 separate columns PRODUCT_ID, PRODUCT_SIZE_ID, QUANTITY so that you can handle all possible combinations of `(product, size)`. The actual products will be in table PRODUCTS (referenced by PRODUCT_ID) and the actual codes or any other information about the sizes will be in table SIZES (referenced by PRODUCT_SIZE_ID).

Comment: the theory of my setup is just a different way to storing the data. What i want it to do (i.e find the ID of the item, once checkout, it updates the quantity of the item and doesnt add the other items from the cart into the field.) i can't work out what part of my code is truly causing this annoying issue...

Comment: Please provide (1) contents of the cart, (2) contents of the products, (3) expected result for products after executing your code, (3) actual result for products after executing your code.

Comment: Ivo - I have just edited my original post to answer the 4 questions you have asked. Thanks for taking time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach of saving multiple values in a single cell is wrong - your table should actually look like that:

```
+------------+---------+----------+
| Product_id | Size_id | Quantity |
+------------+---------+----------+
|     247    |    7    |     20   |
+------------+---------+----------+
|     242    |    4    |     20   |
+------------+---------+----------+
```

and in addition you will need 2 other tables - PRODUCTS and SIZES:

```
+------------+--------------+
| product_id | product_name |
+------------+--------------+
|     247    | Jacket       |
+------------+--------------+
|     242    | Shoe         |
+------------+--------------+

+---------+-----------+
| size_id | size_name |
+---------+-----------+
|   7     | W5000W    |
+---------+-----------+
|   4     | MK120     |
+---------+-----------+
```

Anyway, if you want to continue using your data model, then the code should look like this:

```
function sizesToArray($string)
{
  $sizesArray = explode(',',$string);
  $returnArray = array();
  foreach($sizesArray as $size)
  {
    $s = explode(':',$size);
    // by using keyed array you are saving the FOREACH-loop 
    // for finding the relevant size
    $returnArray[$s[0]] = $s[1];
  }
  return $returnArray;
}

// you can also use array_map() to return an array of "SIZE:QUANTITY" elements
// and then use implode(",") on it
function sizesToString($sizes)
{
  $sizesString = '';
  // $sizes is keyed by SIZE_NAME
  foreach($sizes as $size_name => $size_qty)
  {
    $sizesString .= $size_name.':'.$size_qty.',';
  }
  $trimmed = rtrim($sizesString, ',');
  return $trimmed;
}

$itemQ = $db->query("SELECT * FROM cart WHERE id = '{$cart_id}'");
$iresults = mysqli_fetch_assoc($itemQ);
$items = json_decode($iresults['items'],true);

foreach($items as $item)
{
  $item_id = $item['id'];
  $productQ = $db->query("SELECT sizes FROM products WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
  $product = mysqli_fetch_assoc($productQ);
  $sizes = sizesToArray($product['sizes']);
  $sizes[$item['size']] -= $item['quantity']; // we deduce the relevant q-ty
  $sizesString = sizesToString($sizes);
  $db->query("UPDATE products SET sizes = '{$sizesString}' WHERE id = '{$item_id}'");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ivo, I will try these suggestions and see how I get on.

Comment: Ivo, it worked and my quantities update now using the original string. I do have an issue where i check for available stock levels, so that if someones goes to order to than what is available it won't let them. Before i changed my code to your suggestions it gave me the correct error message now it just adds the value to the cart without checking. 

I have this code:

Comment: I have edited my original post to include new information. The theory behind the validation is correct and should work, but i have a feeling because i changed the array to the suggestions about the validation isn't recognizing what to check for "available"..

Comment: If there is no more stock of the given size - your `option` tag is missing `data-available="0"`. Also, you are updating the value of `#available` only when the currently selected option in the drop-down list is changed - so if the use does not change what is selected by default then you have an empty `#available`.

Comment: Ivo, I left the option box like this: 

if ($available > 0){
                echo '<option value="'.$size.'" data-available="'.$available.'">'.$size.' 
                ('.$available.' Available)</option>';
            }
            if ($available <= 0){
              echo '<option value="">No more left</option>';
            }

but i was missing the hidden input just as the form was declared. 
I therefore added this line, and it works:
        <input type="hidden" name="available" id="available" value="">

Thanks for your help.